# How to get the black solid object alone ignoring white island using python

Tags: opencv, image-processing

After Appling image processing technics i got the input image, now i need the out put as shown in attachment:

[image]

How can i deleted all the white island and keep only solid black object
Any techniques available, please do suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of single pixels or small clusters, you can use morphological operations.
The opencv opening function removes small objects.

```
dst=open(src,element)=dilate(erode(src,element))
```

where element is the kernel for the dilation and erosion and src the source image.

The opencv [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dbe/tutorial_opening_closing_hats.html) is very helpful on this.

To find closed contours, you could use the `findContours` function after the morphological operations.
[Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html)